# SQL - Combine Columns

Tags: sql

I have to create invoice report from two different table.

One table includes all information but data represented for different GL codes per invoice in one line.

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.Document (

    ID                       int           NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ExternalID               nvarchar(256)     NULL,
    "GUID"                   nvarchar(100)     NULL,
    DeletionStatus           nvarchar(100)     NULL,
    LatestVersion            int               NULL,
    CheckedOutTo_User_ID     int               NULL,
    CheckedOutAt             datetime          NULL,
    Files                    int               NULL,
    TotalFileSize            bigint            NULL,
    Class_ID                 int               NULL,
    "Name or title"          nvarchar(100)     NULL,
    Keywords                 nvarchar(100)     NULL,
    Created                  datetime          NULL,
    "AP Name"                nvarchar(100)     NULL,
    "Invoice Number"         nvarchar(100)     NULL,
    Code                     nvarchar(100)     NULL,
    "Invoice Date"           datetime          NULL,
    "Due Date"               datetime          NULL,
    "Invoice Total"          float             NULL,
    "Partial Payment"        float             NULL,
    Terms_Term_ID            int               NULL,
    Discounts                float             NULL,
    "Description"            ntext             NULL,
    "GL Codes #1_GL Code_ID" int               NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo."GL Code" ( "ID" ),
    "GL Amount #1"           float             NULL,
    "GL Codes #2_GL Code_ID" int               NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo."GL Code" ( "ID" ),
    "GL Amount #2"           float             NULL,
    "GL Codes #3_GL Code_ID" int               NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo."GL Code" ( "ID" ),
    "GL Amount #3"           float             NULL,
    "GL Codes #4_GL Code_ID" int               NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo."GL Code" ( "ID" ),
    "GL Amount #4"           float             NULL,
    "GL Codes #5_GL Code_ID" int               NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo."GL Code" ( "ID" ),
    "GL Amount #5"           float             NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo."GL Code" (

    ID               int           NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "ExternalID"     nvarchar(256)     NULL,
    "GUID"           nvarchar(100)     NULL,
    "DeletionStatus" nvarchar(100)     NULL,
    "Name"           nvarchar(100)     NULL,
    "Owner"          int               NULL
);
```

As you can see first invoice amount appears like sum of `gl_code1+glcode2+gl_code3`

The second line includes only one representation gl_code1

[image]

I have to show all amount per GL code and I decided to use table GL Code and Join to this table all other information. But I have a lot of nulls and I don't know how to combine data in the column

[image]

[image]

How can I modify the query to get the result in right side of the screenshot?

Comment: please create a fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7bce0/1 provide the tables and some sample data. pasted images does not help at all.

Comment: you can download sql for recreate same table structure https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b4Qr1vDOo550wYdaobCs1Ti_sSNqg3ZK/view?usp=sharing     Thank you

Comment: some data is more than welcome :)

Comment: Read up on `UNPIVOT`.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @knot22 SELECT
      [Invoice Number]

      ,[GL Amount #1] as GL_A

      ,[GL Amount #2] as GL_A
  
  FROM 
  (select [Invoice Number],[GL Amount #1],[GL Amount #2]
 from [dbo].[Document] 
  ) d
  Unpivot
  (Orders for GL_A IN
  ([GL Amount #1],[GL Amount #2])
  )as unpvt
 it is not working

Comment: How many "GL" columns are there? Will there ever be less-than - or more-than 3? Your first screenshot shows at least 5, and maybe more... If the columns are defined at runtime (e.g. using Dynamic SQL) then you won't be able to do this using `UNPIVOT` (or any SQL at all, really...): you'll need to use Dynamic-SQL yourself - but ideally can't you get direct access the normalized data-sources without getting these numbered columns?

Comment: You were asked for a SQLFiddle/DBFiddle link, not _just_ your `CREATE TABLE` statements - but I've added them to your question anyway. I noticed that _all_ of your table columns are `NULL`-able - why is this?

Comment: I see you have `"Invoice Total"  float  NULL` - this is a **bad design**: you should never use `float` for monetary amounts. Is there any way you can correct the design of this table, or otherwise admonish whoever did design this table?

Comment: Select [Invoice Number],[Code] as [Vendor],[Invoice Date],[Invoice Total],GL_AMOUNT, Document1 
 from 
( select [Invoice Number],[Code],[Invoice Date],[Invoice Total],[GL Amount #1],[GL Amount #2],[GL Amount #3],[GL Amount #4],[GL Amount #5] 
from [dbo].[Document] ) origdocs
unpivot
(Document1 for GL_AMOUNT IN ([GL Amount #1],[GL Amount #2],[GL Amount #3],[GL Amount #4],[GL Amount #5] )) as unpivottable   This is final Code. Working perfect, Thanks to  @knot22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample data used in `dbo.Document`:
[image]

This normalizes the data:

```
select
[Invoice Number],
[GL Code_ID],
[GL Amount],
--next 4 columns are displayed for visibility of how this unpivot works - they can be commented out or not included at all
[GL Code_ID Label],
[GL Amount Label],
[GL Code_ID Label parsed] = substring([GL Code_ID Label], charindex('#', [GL Code_ID Label]), 2),
[GL Amount Label parsed] = substring([GL Amount Label], charindex('#', [GL Amount Label]), 2)
from dbo.Document
unpivot ([GL Code_ID] for [GL Code_ID Label] in ([GL Codes #1_GL Code_ID], [GL Codes #2_GL Code_ID], [GL Codes #3_GL Code_ID])) u1
unpivot ([GL Amount] for [GL Amount Label] in ([GL Amount #1], [GL Amount #2], [GL Amount #3])) u2
where substring([GL Code_ID Label], charindex('#', [GL Code_ID Label]), 2) = substring([GL Amount Label], charindex('#', [GL Amount Label]), 2);  --join condition for unpivots
```

Result:

[image]

This intermediate dataset can be put into a temp table or a CTE, then joining to `dbo.[GL Codes]` from there and calculating invoice totals is a trivial exercise.

Note that the above code only used GL #1 to #3 as that was the sample data that was populated.  Just follow the pattern to add #4 and #5 in the unpivots.

Answer (score 0):

Three left joins does not make sense, maybe an approach with COALESCE works. There is a lack of input but try this i have also provided a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2b8c7/32)

```
Select gl.id,doc.[Invoice Number],doc.[Invoice Total],gl.[name], COALESCE([GL Amount #1],[GL Amount #2],[GL Amount #3]) as [GL Amount Bill]
from [GL Code] gl,[Document] doc
where doc.[GL Codes #1_GL Code_ID]=gl.ID or doc.[GL Codes #2_GL Code_ID]=gl.ID or doc.[GL Codes #3_GL Code_ID]=gl.ID
order by gl.Id
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I can't use in statement OR because I have to represent all values. in our case this will be only first value GL-Code1 and if I have all five this query will show me only first with value 100.    this solution is working  with unpivot but I still have problem representing proper GL Account  15  Digits

Comment: Select 
 [Code] as [Vendor],
 [Invoice Number],
 [Invoice Date], 
 glCodeAmmount as [Transition Amount] ,
 [Invoice Total] as [Transition Balance],
 GL_ACCOUNT_ID as [GL Account],
 [Description] as [PO Number]
FROM 
 (select 
  [Invoice Number],
  [Code],
  [Invoice Date],
  [Invoice Total],
  [Description],
  [GL Amount #1],
  [GL Amount #2],
  [GL Amount #3],
  [GL Amount #4],
  [GL Amount #5] 
 FROM [dbo].[Document] 
 ) origdocs
unpivot
(glCodeAmmount for GL_ACCOUNT_ID IN ([GL Amount #1],[GL Amount #2],[GL Amount #3],[GL Amount #4],[GL Amount #5] )) as unpivottable